# clip-path two triangles on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I've recently been keen to learn more about CSS having primarily always been more backend focused.

I'm currently trying to position two images, using `clip-path` on top of each other. The top triangle will be upside down and the bottom the correct way up to form a header. Ideally with a white gap between them to separate them slightly.

This is essentially what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: what I'm trying to achieve]

Currently, I have a header with two divs inside of it:

```
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="triangle-top"></div>
    <div class="triangle-bottom"></div>
  </header>
</body>
```

I also have this styling:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #777;
  padding: 30px;
}

.header {
  height: 95vh;
{

.triangle-top {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(54, 0, 51, 0.8), rgba(11, 136, 147, 0.8)), url(../img/hero.jpg);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  height: 95vh;
}

.triangle-bottom {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(54, 0, 51, 0.8), rgba(11, 136, 147, 0.8)), url(../img/hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  height: 95vh;
}
```

I did have the `background-size` and `background-cover` defined in the `.header` class but nothing rendered unless I specified them separately. Currently, I can see both triangles, but there is a massive gap between them like so:

[image: current output]

As you can see the start of the second triangle is right at the bottom of the page.

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you need to make one position absolute

Comment: from the duplicate replace the gradient with your images. Also note that you only need one clip-path